# Is it possible for the child of a div set to pointer-events: none to have pointer events?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible for the child of a div set to `pointer-events: none` to have pointer events?

I need the div that holds another div to allow pointer events to pass through, but for the div itself to still have events.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 231, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, and you basically just described how. Disable it for the parent and enable it for the child.

[**`pointer-events`**](https://caniuse.com/pointer-events) is supported in almost every browser, including **IE11**

Please note that `pointer-events: all` is for **SVG only**.

For HTML, only `auto` and `none` are supported values.

```css
.parent {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.child {
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <a href="#">Parent</a>
  <div class="child">
    <a href="#">Child</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4gQkT/

Comment: wooo, thank you, I just wasn't aware of the possible `all` value.

Comment: But notice: The use of pointer-events in CSS for non-SVG elements is experimental. The feature used to be part of the CSS3 UI draft specification but, due to many open issues, has been postponed to CSS4.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: Additionally, it's not supported by Internet Explorer (not even IE10).

Comment: I have not tested this jsFiddle in particular but I have a similar setup and in IE11 this does not work (the child does not receive any events). Does anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: If you want to enable pointer events for all children, instead of adding a class to all of them, you can use the child selector `.parent *`

Comment: Wouldn't of thought this would be possible considering how `z-index` works.

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) says `pointer-events:all` is SVG-only.  While this does work, `pointer-events:auto` might be clearer.

Answer (score 16):

On the child element's style, add

```
pointer-events: auto;
```

`pointer-events: all` didn't work for me, and apparently applies to SVG elements only.

Answer (score -4):

My solution:

```
.mouse-false * {
  pointer-events: none;
}

<button class='mouse-false'>
 <i>e</i> test
</button>
```

Comment: This is the opposite of what @fancy is asking, they want the container to have no pointer events but the child to have them

Answer (score -5):

As a possible solution in some cases you can set

```css
height: 0;
```

to parent element and let child element to overflow